# Why is Iris merging coordinates from different pressure domain profiles?

Tags: python, python-iris

I am loading in air temperature on pressure levels (STASH code 30294) from some UM output and Iris appears to be incorrectly interpreting the data.

This variable is being written to a file with two different domain profiles; (1) 19 pressure levels (`PLEV19`), (2) 27 pressure levels (`PLEV27`).

These variables show up as expected when viewed with `Xconv` but when read in with `iris.load(...)` the resulting `CubeList` contains two seemingly identical cubes with 34 pressure levels.

It turns out that the 34 pressure levels that are being returned are in fact all the *unique* pressure values from the two different variables and so - I think - that the variables are being incorrectly merged?

This is illustrated in the code below where `cubes` is a `CubeList` containing the two cubes which should have different numbers of pressure levels.

Fundamentally my question is; how can I load in the two variables as two separate cubes in Iris?

Any help appreciated!

[image]